# Fixing Undefined Label Error - Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, label

I'm trying to stop function execution after the condition is met - however, keep getting the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'my_loop'

Here is my code:

```
        my_loop:
        for (var i = 0; i < fatterkwslist.length; i++) {
            console.log(fatterkwslist[i] + " " + "in your list");
            (function (i) { 
                setTimeout(function() { 
                    if (innerText === "Search blocked.") {
                        break my_loop;
                } else {

                    document.querySelector(".result-disclaimer").innerText = "keywords checked" + " " + (i + 1) + "/" + fatterkwslist.length; 
                    var history = {
                        "keyword": fatterkwslist[i],
                        "domain": domain,
                        "country": window.localStorage[RC.storageVars.country_url]
                    };
                    RC.queryHistory.push(history);

                    bgPage.RC.googleSearch.findPosition(fatterkwslist[i]  ,
                        domain,
                        window.localStorage[RC.storageVars.country_url],
                        RC.renderResult);
                        RC.hideLoaded();
            }}, 1000*i)  }) (i);
     };
```

Not sure how can I make label visible for setTimeout.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is out of context. Please explain what is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hello Ahmad, thank you for your comment. Essentially I'm trying to exit the for loop after the condition is met.

Comment: The for loop doesn’t wait for your timeout. The loop is over before the first timeout fires.

Comment: `setTimeout` will execute some time later, and not inside your loop. Plus, when it runs, `break` will no longer take any effect on your loop, since as @MarkMeyer , it does not wait

Comment: @MarkMeyer, Ahmad amazing, thank you very much that makes sense now!